# Data on a webpage depends on Form Entry- how to get access to the forms source data?

Tags: python, html, forms

I have a website that i would like to scrape from:

https://www.visionsuper.com.au/index.php?option=com_unitprices&Itemid=305

The website is fairly basic- there is a form that the user executes to see the data, however, the problem is that the limit of the data is monthly.

It looks as though all the background data is available within the HTML script. as the URL does not change after the form is amended. (im quite new to this so this assumption could be wrong).

Hoping for some assistance to the how to find the entire source.

Or would this require code to automate scraping though a webdriver and clicking on each month

Thanks for any help that can be provided.

Comment: The URL is being POSTed to, with the selected month in the request body. You should be able to look into the details if you open the Network panel in your browser's developer tools and select a month.

Comment: thanks for the response, again im quite new, i went into the devleoper tools in chrome (console) and it keeps coming up with 'DevTools failed to load Source map'